# Monte Carlo Simulation with contingency table in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, montecarlo, contingency

I want to generate the 1000 tables from an existing contingency table and estimate the exact p-value by Monte-Carlo. To do so, I know that the contingency tables have to satisfy the condition S = {p(T) ≤ p (array-observe)}. Then, I have to compute the probabilities of unique tables among the 1000 generated.

I have started a part of the code, but I am stuck in generating the tables respecting the condition mentioned above. I looking for a command that could to so without using the command fisher.test.

Here is my code, where `infarctus.tables` corresponds to the generated tables from a contingency table and `infarctus` is my data.

```
infractus <- matrix(c(6, 4, 2, 0, 7, 4, 1, 0, 2,2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2), nrow = 4, byrow = T)

infarctus.tables ### how do I generate this?

##probabilities of unique tables among the 1000 generated
tables.prob= lapply( unique(infarctus.tables), 
      FUN=function(x) { exp( a1 - sum(lgamma( x + 1) ) ) })
hist( unlist(tables.prob))
obs.prob= which(unlist(tables.prob) <= 0.0164141415 )
```

Any idea on how to do so?

Comment: What is `a1`? The code is giving an `Error: object 'a1' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R includes function `r2dtable`. From the documentation.

> Description
> Generate random 2-way tables with given marginals using Patefield's algorithm.

```r
infractus <- matrix(c(6, 4, 2, 0, 7, 4, 1, 0, 2,2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2), nrow = 4, byrow = T)

rsums <- rowSums(infractus)
csums <- colSums(infractus)
n <- 5
r2dtable(n, rsums, csums)
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    3    5    4    0
#> [2,]    6    3    1    2
#> [3,]    3    4    3    2
#> [4,]    5    3    1    3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    8    3    1    0
#> [2,]    1    6    2    3
#> [3,]    4    3    4    1
#> [4,]    4    3    2    3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    4    3    3    2
#> [2,]    5    4    2    1
#> [3,]    6    1    3    2
#> [4,]    2    7    1    2
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    4    5    2    1
#> [2,]    4    6    1    1
#> [3,]    7    1    3    1
#> [4,]    2    3    3    4
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    3    4    4    1
#> [2,]    5    4    2    1
#> [3,]    7    2    1    2
#> [4,]    2    5    2    3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

To generate 1000 matrices with the given marginals, run

```
n <- 1000L
infarctus.tables <- r2dtable(n, rsums, csums)
```